# struct addrinfo undeclared in Xcode 4

Tags: objective-c, c, sockets, xcode4, ios-frameworks

I'm running in to some strange errors when dabbling in some socket programming using Xcode 4. I get the error that `addrinfo` is undeclared, despite me simply copying the code from another project that did work (when using Xcode 3). The project is mainly in Objective-C, but I've tested creating another framework with plain C, and the error still remains.

I have the following frameworks included:

- ApplicationServices.framework
- Cocoa.framework
- AppKit.framework
- Foundation.framework

No added linker flags either.

However, other functions such as getaddrinfo (that uses `addrinfo` itself!) exists. Any ideas?

Comment: Does netdb.h typedef the struct? Maybe your previous code did and it wasn't copied over.

Comment: @zjaquish: That did it! (Almost) As I recall the previous projects were in c++, so I guess the semantics for structs changed causing this error when chaning to c/objective-c. What do I have to do to fix this? The header netdb.h doesn't typedef the struct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue wasn't IDE-related, it was a language issue. How structs are treated is apparently different in C (and thus Objective-c) and C++ (which the previous projects were=. So I changed the line

```
addrinfo hints;
```

To:

```
struct addrinfo hints;
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you got the correct imports?

```
#import <netinet/in.h>
#import <sys/socket.h>
```

Comment: Yeah. I have: stdlib.h, sys/types.h, sys/socket.h, netdb.h, arpa/inet.h. And adding netinet/in.h didn't help, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

A quick grep shows that struct addrinfo is declared in <netdb.h>. Try explicitly including that. (Your Xcode 3 project may have included that, or some other header that includes it, in its prefix file.)

Comment: I have that included already. Command-clicking the header link "#include <netdb.h>" shows that it's declared there, but nothing.